# I can't set custom properties Unity PUN 2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, multiplayer, photon

I'm making a multiplayer game in which everyone has gold or bomb variable. I want to set this with custom properties but I'm getting null reference error:
`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Here is my PlayerController code:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable myCustomProperties = new ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable();
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public Player player;
    public int playerID;
    public int[] goldArray = { 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 30, 50, 75, 100 };

    private void Start()
    {
        SetCustomProps();
        Debug.Log(PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.CustomProperties);
    }
 
    /*private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            Debug.Log("space pressed!");
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            //swapBomb(other);
        }
    }*/
    /*private void swapBomb(Collider other)
    {

    }*/

    public void SetCustomProps()
    {
        int gold = (int)PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.CustomProperties["Gold"];    //error
        gold = goldArray[Random.Range(0, goldArray.Length)] * 10;
        myCustomProperties.Add("Gold", gold);

        bool bomb = (bool)PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.CustomProperties["Bomb"];
        bomb = false;
        myCustomProperties.Add("Bomb", bomb);

        PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.SetCustomProperties(myCustomProperties);   //error
    }
}
```

Comment: probably it is looking for local player in inspector. Where do you assign ViewID to player? Also how do you instantiate the player?

Comment: I instantiate the player with this line:
`PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("PhotonPrefabs", "PhotonPlayer"), Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);`


I guess I did not assign ViewID, where should I assign it?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for choosing Photon!

Initially, the player does not have "Gold" and "Bomb" properties.
Hence the NullReferenceException when trying to get and cast those.

But do you really need to get the old or current values first?
It looks like you override those anyways.

So I would first check if they exist using `ContainsKey` or `TryGetValue`.

Example 1:

```
    public void SetCustomProps()
    {
        object temp;
        if (PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.CustomProperties.TryGetValue("Gold", out temp))
        { 
           int gold = (int)temp;
```

Example 2:

```
        if (PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.CustomProperties.ContainsKey("Bomb"))
        { 
           bool bomb = (bool)PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.CustomProperties["Bomb"];
```

Side notes:

- it's best practice to use static fields or constants for custom property keys strings instead of hardcoded ones here and there. this will help you avoid issues of keys mismatch as they are case sensitive.
- if `myCustomProperties` field is used only inside SetCustomProperties, maybe it makes sense to use it as a local variable there only.
- maybe you need to set initial custom properties before joining rooms in a separate method. this way you end up with initial values on join direcly.